# How to SET an output value of a SELECT statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

So, I am creating a mysql EVENT that computes the sales every month from transaction_tbl. I can't find the error I made.

Here's my query:

```
DELIMITER |

 CREATE EVENT compute_sales
 ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2018-10-01 22:00.00'
 DO
      BEGIN

 DECLARE mmsales DECIMAL(11, 2)
 SET mmsales = SELECT SUM(total_amount)
           FROM transaction_tbl
           WHERE MONTH(transaction_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
                YEAR(transaction_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())

 INSERT INTO sales_tbl (sales_year, sales_month, total_sales, time_frame) VALUES 
          (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTHNAME(CURRENT_DATE), mmsales, CURRENT_DATE)

 END |

 DELIMITER ;
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET mmsales = SELECT SUM(total_amount)
>                  FROM transaction_tbl' at line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need brackets:

```
SET mmsales = (SELECT SUM(total_amount)
               FROM transaction_tbl
               WHERE MONTH(transaction_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
                 AND YEAR(transaction_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()));
```

Plus you should end each statement with semicolon.